# Working with the State monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I have been learning some Haskell little by little and am (slowly) working on understanding the State monad, attempting to write a function that repeats a State computation until the state meets some boolean test and collecting the returned values in a list for the overall result.  I finally succeeded with this:

```
collectUntil :: (s -> Bool) -> State s a -> State s [a]
collectUntil f s = do s0 <- get
                      let (a,s') = runState s s0
                      put s'
                      if (f s') then return [a] else liftM (a:) $ collectUntil f s
```

so that

```
simpleState = state (\x -> (x,x+1))

*Main> evalState (collectUntil (>10) simpleState) 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Is this a reasonable function for this task, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: The idiomatic way would most likely involve a bit more general function, such as `Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m [a]`. Using `untilM` from `monad-loops`, you get: `untilM simpleState (liftM (> 10) get)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are making exactly the same mistakes that I made when I first started writing monadic code - making it way too complicated, overusing `liftM` and underusing `>>=` (equivalently, underusing the `<-` notation).

Ideally, you shouldn't have to mention `runState` or `evalState` inside the state monad at all. The functionality you want is as follows:

- Read the current state
- If it satisfies the predicate `f`, then return
- If not, then run the computation `s` and add its result to the output

You can do this quite directly as:

```
collectUntil f comp = do
    s <- get                              -- Get the current state
    if f s then return []                 -- If it satisfies predicate, return
           else do                        -- Otherwise...
               x  <- comp                 -- Perform the computation s
               xs <- collectUntil f comp  -- Perform the rest of the computation
               return (x:xs)              -- Collect the results and return them
```

Note that you can nest do statements if they are part of the same monad! This is very useful - it allows you to branch within one do block, as long as both branches of the if statement lead to something of the same monadic type.

The inferred type for this function is:

```
collectUntil :: MonadState t m => (t -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
```

If you wish, you can specialise that to the `State s` type, although you don't have to:

```
collectUntil :: (s -> Bool) -> State s a -> State s [a]
```

It might even be preferable to keep the more general state, in case you want to use a different monad later.

#### What's the intuition?

Whenever `s` is a stateful computation and you are inside the state monad, you can do

```
x <- s
```

and `x` will now have the result of the computation (as if you'd called `evalState` and fed in an initial state). If you ever need to check the state, you can do

```
s' <- get
```

and `s'` will have the value of the current state.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I think part of my confusion was treating the state argument `s` as a completely _separate_ computation that I had to evaluate explicitly with `runState` and inject its resulting state into the current computation with `put`.  Thanks to @Heatsink for the same insight.

Answer (score 4):

Most monads come with a few primitive "run" operations such as `runState`, `execState`, and so forth.  If you are frequently calling `runState` *inside* the state monad, it means you are not really using the functionality the monad provides.  You have written

```
s0 <- get                    -- Read state
let (a,s') = runState s s0   -- Pass state to 's', get new state
put s'                       -- Save new state
```

You do not have to explicitly pass the state around.  This is what the state monad does! You can just write

```
a <- s
```

Otherwise, the function looks reasonable.  Since `a` is part of the result in both branches of the 'if', I would suggest factoring that out for clarity.

```
collectUntil f s = step
  where
    step = do a <- s
              liftM (a:) continue
    continue = do s' <- get
                  if f s' then return [] else step
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple task I would not use the `State` monad. The others already clarified how you actually should write the monadic version, but I would like to add my personal (simpler) solution since you're asking for the most idiomatic way to write that.

```
collectWhile, collectUntil :: (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a]
collectWhile f cond z = takeWhile cond $ iterate f z
collectUntil f cond z = collectWhile f (not . cond) z
```

Alternatively, just the following line is enough if you only want `collectUntil`

```
collectUntil f cond z = takeWhile (not.cond) $ iterate f z
```

Here [takeWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3atakeWhile) and [iterate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aiterate) are from [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html). For completeness, as it's the core of the implementation, the following is the (very simple) code for iterate:

```
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

**warning**: probably this wasn't clear enough from my answer, but this solution isn't really the same since I fuse together state and result by working outside `State`. Of course one may do something very similar by using `f :: (s, a) -> (s, a)` and then projecting with `map fst` or `map snd` to get respectively the list of intermediate states or results. For ease of notation at this point it may be simpler to use the solution with `State`, though.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing. It returns the sequence of states rather than the sequence of results.

Comment: I know, by putting aside `State` for simplicity I fused together state and result. I'm sorry this wasn't clear enough from my answer. My solution is aimed, as I state in the first line, at simpler tasks as in Dan's example, where state and result are actually are the same thing (e.g. `collectUntil (+1) (>10) 0 == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`).